# Java's pass-by-value has the same effects as C++'s call-by-pointers for class objects?

Tags: java, c++, function-pointers

I have read lots of materials about parameter passings. But still I have a few little questions to ask. I understand how primitive types works, and right now I only care about passing objects as parameters.

Facts:

1. Everything(primitives/objects) in Java is pass-by-value
2. When an object is passed as a parameter in Java, the value of the reference variable is copied and passed. Therefore, any change to the object will be visible when the function exits.
3. In C++, parameter passings could be done in three ways: call-by-value, call-by-pointer and call-by-reference.
4. When an object pointer is passed as a parameter by call-by-pointer, the address of the object(the pointer) is copied and passed. The change will also reflects.

My guess:

Java's pass-by-value has the same effects as C++'s call-by-pointers for class objects?
Am I right?

Comment: Yes. (Well, aside from the explicit dereferencing you'd have to do with a pointer.)

Comment: Not exactly same. For example C++ can have pointer to pointer as function argument such as `void foo(Node **node)`. So in this case, the address pointed by `node` can be changed when returned from the function. But Java doesn't have this.

Comment: I always have doubt for where the term "pass-by-pointer" is coming from.  Just treat there is pass-by-value and pass-by-ref. Period.  Pointer is simply a type, just like integer, or double etc.

Comment: @tonga: The question only talked about pointers to objects in C++. It did not talk about other things, like pointers to pointers. So I don't understand what you are disagreeing with.

Comment: @newacct What I mean in my comment is: In C++, if you pass a pointer to pointer, or a reference to a pointer, then you can change to a new object pointed by the pointer. But this is not achievable by Java. So in Java, you have to return the new object as the return object in the method.

Comment: @tonga: The question is about passing or assigning Java's references vs. C++'s pointers to objects. They are the same. What part of this do you disagree with? Pointers to pointers in C++ is irrelevant. Just because C++ has additional unrelated stuff (taking address of something) Java doesn't have doesn't mean the equivalence between something in Java and something in C++ doesn't hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that the functionality of a Java object reference is basically identical to a C++ pointer except in C++ you can dereference and actually overwrite the memory block the pointer points to. You can't do that in Java.

So a Java object reference is like a C++ pointer but there is no `*` operator. The Java `.` operator is only for member access, like the C++ `->` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Some corrections:

> 1) Everything(primitives/objects) in Java is pass-by-value

Yes, but "objects" is not within "everything". "Objects" are not values in Java. The only types in Java are primitive types and reference types, so the only values in Java are primitives and references (pointers to objects). Not "objects".

> 2) When an object is passed as a parameter in Java,

As above, an "object" is not a value in Java, and cannot be "passed". So this sentence doesn't make sense.

Your conclusions are right. Since references in Java are pointers to objects, they work the same way as pointers to objects in C++.

Answer (score -3):

> Everything(primitives/objects) in Java is pass-by-value
>   When an object is passed as a parameter in Java, the value of the reference variable is copied and passed. Therefore, any change to the object will be visible when the function exits.

Everything in Java is passed by "value" by default, but the "value" that is passed is effectively the pointer (if you think of everything in Java as a pointer - the exception to this being primitives).

> In C++, parameter passings could be done in three ways: call-by-value, call-by-pointer and call-by-reference.
>   Java's pass-by-value has the same effects as C++'s call-by-pointers for class objects?

It is usually referred to as pass-by-value, pass-by-reference, pass-by-const-reference (in C++).  Passing by pointer is just another way to pass-by-value (you are passing the pointer by value, but what the pointer points to effectively by reference) - this is effectively what Java does.  If you change the pointer value, it is not reflected outside the function, but if you change the *data* that is being pointed to, it is ([example](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html))

Comment: Incorrect. **All** Java parameters are pass-by-value, period. In the case of object parameters, the value being passed is a reference, but this is distinct behavior from pass-by-reference (specifically, no out parameters).

Comment: Thank you for quick response. However, I can't agree with you.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry, was getting Java and C# mixed up.  Fixing it now.

Comment: While the use of "pass by value" in the Java community seems a bit inappropriate when you come from the outside, it's *definitely* not the case that *everything* is passed by reference. Primitives not at all in any sense of the word, and for objects neither in the strict, original sense. In particular, it does *not* behave at all like passing by reference in C++ (which in turn does match the traditional definition of pass-by-reference). Try writing a `swap(Object a, Object b)`.

Comment: I'll flip my vote if improved further, but this answer still gives the erroneous impression that pass-by-value is just a Java default. It's the black Model T.

Comment: Re your edit: Still incorrect. You seem to say objects (as opposed to references to them) are copied so that `someMethod(obj)` cannot possible affect the object referenced to by `obj`. That's incorrect as any method of the form `f(T o) { o.mutate() /* or */ o.field = something; }` can attest.

Comment: @delnan True, that wasn't what I was trying to say.  I think I've corrected the verbiage on that.